# Proving a theorem about 'three-elements-set'

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I found a theorem in a book without any addtional information. I've tried to know its name and its proof, but I haven't been able to find them. Do you know the name of the following theorem? Or could you show me how to prove the theorem?

**Theorem**: Let $n\ge4$. Let's choose three out of the natural numbers from $1$ to $n$, and make a subset of them. Let's call it **three-elements-set**. Note that there exist $_nC_3$ three-elements-sets. Letting $N$ be the maximum number of three-elements-sets under the following condition, then the equality of $N\le\frac16n(n-1)$ is attained if and only if $n=6m+1, 6m+3$.

**Condition**: For any different two of the $N$ three-elements-sets, the number of the common elements is less than or equal to $1$.

**Motivation** : I've already proved the following two.

*1*. $N\le\frac16n(n-1)$.

**Proof**: Let's start to prove that the number of three-elements-sets which have $1$ is less than or equals to $\frac{n-1}{2}$ under the condition.

If two three-elements-sets have $1$, they must not have the other common elements. Then, by separating $n-1$ three-elements-sets into pairs of two, we get that the number of pairs is $\frac{n-1}{2}$ at most, so the proof of the first paragraph is completed. By the same argument as above, we get that the number of three-elements-sets which have each of $1, 2, \cdots, n$ is less than or equals to $\frac{n-1}{2}$. Noting that we count one three-elements-set three times, we get $$N\le n\cdot\frac{n-1}{2}\div3=\frac{n(n-1)}{6}.$$

*2*. The equality of $N\le\frac16n(n-1)$ is attained if $n=3^m \ (m\ge2)$.

**Proof**: Let's prove this by mathematical induction. The case $m=2$ is the following:
$\{1,2,3\}, \{1,4,5\}, \{1,6,7\}, \{1,8,9\}, \{2,4,6\}, \{2,5,8\}, \{2,7,9\}, \{3,4,9\}, \{3,5,7\}, \{3,6,8\}, \{4,7,8\}, \{5,6,9\}.$

Suppose that the equality is attained if $n=3^m$. Let's separate the natural numbers from $1$ to $3^{m+1}$ into the following three sets:$$A=\{k: 1\le k \le 3^m\}, B=\{k: 3^m+1\le k \le 2\cdot 3^m\}, C=\{k: 2\cdot 3^m+1\le k\le 3^{m+1}\}.$$

By the supposition, we get $\frac{3^m(3^m-1)}{6}$ three-elements-sets in each of $A,B,C$$\ \cdots (i)$.

Next, for $a\in A, b\in B$, choosing $c\in C$ such that $$a+b=c \mod\  3^m\ \cdots (ii),$$ let's determine the three-elements-set $\{a,b,c\}$. Each of $a,b$ has $3^m$ cases, so there exist $9^m$ cases of $\{a,b,c\}$ which satisfy $(ii)$. Here, by $(ii)$, if we determine the two of $a,b,c$, then the other one is determined, so the number of the common elements of any of two of $9^m$ $\{a,b,c\}$s is less than or equals to 1. The number of the common elements of any three-elements-sets of each of $(i)$ and $(ii)$ is less than or equals to $1$, so these satisfy the condition. Hence, the sum of three-elements-set is the following:$$3\cdot \frac{3^m(3^m-1)}{6}+9^m=\frac{3^{m+1}(3^{m+1}-1)}{6}.$$So, the equality is attained if $n=3^{m+1}$. Now, the proof is completed.

Comment: Sounds like it may be a Ramsey-type theorem?

Comment: @FBD: Thank you. I checked the theorem, but I don't think it is what I want.